# Bootstrap multiple models in same page give same for all models

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I have made about 5 models in a single page using bootstrap with username,password,email,mobile and student are different models but all the buttons give the same model of that of username button even I change the id in each element my code is

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Account settings</h2>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-10">username :  <?php $name = 
$_SESSION['username']; echo $name;?></label>
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal">change username</button>
  </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Change username</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <center>old username:  <?php $name = $_SESSION['username']; echo 
$name;?></center><br>
      new username : <input type="text">
      <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-10">password :  <?php $name = 
  $_SESSION['password']; echo $name;?></label>
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal">change password</button>
  </div>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">change password</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img id="myImg" src="1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="400" 
height="300">
      <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="container">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-10">email :  <?php $name = 
$_SESSION['email']; echo $name;?></label>
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal">change email</button>
  </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
     </button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img id="myImg" src="1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="400" 
   height="300">
      <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-10">mobile numb:  <?php $name = 
 $_SESSION['mobile']; echo $name;?></label>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#myModal">change mobile</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal4" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
  </button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img id="myImg" src="1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="400" 
   height="300">
      <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><br>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal">Add student</button>
  </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal5" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img id="myImg" src="1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="400" 
height="300">
      <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough code here and it looks like it's db-related. Plus, where `$_SESSION['username']` is assigned from is unknown.

Comment: You've an answer below now, see that.

Comment: actually $_SESSION['username'] is included in another file I am using it by writing include(../login1.php')

Comment: this is only the snippet which i have problem

Comment: and the answer given below? did you try that?

Comment: yes it got corrcect i forget in changing the data-targetof my model so that all of them are targetting to same model all the times thankyou Fred -ii- and kamran jabbar

Comment: Great, glad to hear it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add related ids in buttons as well. You are only targeting the myModal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#myModal">change mobile</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#myModal4">change mobile</button>
```